# VMware on Ubuntu- Installed windows in VM - USB Issues

Tags: drivers, windows-7, usb-drive, vmware

I am running ubuntu 14.04 on my laptop, I have installed VMware and installed windows on there, when i plug in my USB stick, the host takes control and the light shows up on my usb to show its working, however when i go to take control on the VM off the usb, Windows will not pick it up on there?, VMware recognizes it, windows recognizes it on my desktop, just the virtual windows will not pick it up.

If i go to device manager on the emulated windows it says there is a problem with the USB Connector Driver, However i have searched online and cannot find a driver for the problem?

If anyone has had a similar or the same issue please help me resolve this

Comment: Which Windows was installed?  (it's not an Ubuntu issue though)

Comment: Windows 7, i thought it may be a conflict as im new to linux and never had this problem on windows before

Comment: screenshot your USB Controller settings for the VM.  Upload to imgur and provide a link.  Also read my answer.

Comment: Will try windows 8, Thank you for your assistance

Comment: let me know.  If my answer helped please feel free to accept my answer.  Also, USB 3.0 is reverse compatible with 2.0, but your host machine has to support USB 3.0 for it all to work too.  :)

Comment: It woirked thanks, would the key i originally have on my bios be suitable for a vm?

Comment: It depends - Installed version must match the key and the key must not be used or Microsoft may say "Sorry your key is already in use" and you will have to call them to try and argue the case.  You most likely though will need to purchase a new key as it's considered its own "system" and install.

Comment: Thought that would be the case, thanks for your help buddy :D

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is actually a Windows Guest issue, not one with Ubuntu, so this should be migrated elsewhere, in my opinion.

Use USB 2.0 instead of USB 3.0 emulation.  Only Win8+ has USB 3.0 native drivers as part of Windows, so only USB 2.0 emulation will work with Win7 and older guest OSes.

I know this because setting up the VM I use for forensics in Windows ran into this issue.  USB 2.0 emulation worked, but 3.0 failed because there's no native Windows USB 3.0 driver in Win7 and earlier (they are proprietary drivers from manufacturers for bare metal installs)